# Which cable for 230.4 Kbps RS-232

Tags: uart, communication, cables, rs232

I have to communicate between a sensor module and micro-controller board. The sensor module uses UART at 230400 bps. I have used a MAX3227 on sensor module as well as micro-controller board. So, the signal levels will be +5V and -5V. The distance between the two circuits will be 3 meters.

The baud rate and distance are fixed and cannot be changed.

I am confused about what cable should I use. I read that twisted pair for Rx-Tx will cause crosstalk. Please suggest me what cable I should select. Thanks!

Comment: What cable do you have?

Comment: None. I plan to order one for this purpose.

Comment: 230400 bps is really pushing RS-232 to its limits. With a 3 meter cable, I'm afraid it's going to be difficult. I have seen specs indicating 2.6 meters max at 56000 bps.

Comment: Here is a reference: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/serial-distance.html. Here is also a table from CISCO (those guys probably know what they're talking about): https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/10000-series-routers/46800-cab232mtfc.html#limits. It only goes up to 115200 bauds, but if you extrapolate, that gives less than 2 meters at your speed. RS-232 is one of the worst ways to transmit a signal. You should probably use something more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks dim, I realize I made a wrong choice. Since PCBs for prototype are on their way, I'll test them with a much shorter cable. 

Should I switch to RS-485 ?

Comment: RS-485 is a much better choice, indeed. And Cat5 cable will be fine for RS-485 (although there is a small impedance mismatch: 100 vs 120 ohm, but it shouldn't matter in your case).

Comment: @dim These lengths come from the RS-232 standard and are for the worst possible (allowed) cable with a really high capacitance (2500pF) - A good shielded cable at 3m will be about 250pF, so we can multiply the maximum lengths by a factor of 10 (minus safety margin).

Comment: @asdfex It makes sense. But I'm surprised that cisco, who provides its own serial cables (that I hope aren't too bad given their price), still specifies such low performances.

Comment: Just as a side note: 230.4 kbd is really an unusual baud rate. Are you sure that your sensor is using that, and that it's not just its maximum rate?

Comment: @Marcus Yes it's 230400 baud. The sensor is an accelerometer module from Murata used for sleep sensing. https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/accel/sca10h_11h/product%20specification%201322%20rev3%20sca10h%20product%20datasheet%20eng.ashx?la=en-us

Comment: @dim because it is the standard, everything more performant is not RS-232 in a strict sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely working with RS-232, but you need to take a bit of care.

- I'd use a shielded cable, standard network cable Cat. 5e or better will do. You can use one pair for RX and one pair for TX. The second wire of each pair can be tied to ground. 
  Using just two wires to transmit the data will very likely not work.
- 230 kBaud should be possible using the driver you mentioned. It is specified up to 1 MBaud at a line capacity of 1 nF. Your 3m cable will be much lower.
- I would add a low-pass filter close to the driver to reduce the slope of the signal and reduce cross-talk and reflections. As every bit has a length of about 5µs, you need an RC-time of less than 1µs, e.g. 1 kOhm in series followed by 100 pF to ground. A termination resistor at the far end might help as well, e.g. 5 kOhm to ground. You might have to play a bit with these values and check the signal quality.

Comment: I should ground the second (ground) wire in each pair only at one end, right?

Comment: No, at both ends is fine. You need to have a ground connection between the two boards. This could be any other wire as well, but the second wire in the pair is a good choice for this (keeping the current loop small)

Comment: I agree that there should be ground connection between two boards. In this case, there will be 2 ground wires (one in TX pair and other in RX pair). 
Wouldn't it create a loop if there are two ground wires between two boards, connected at both ends?

The same kind of loop which we avoid by connecting shield at only 1 end.

Comment: Technically speaking, yes. But this loop is to tiny, you won't see any real-world effect in a cable similar to a network cable. It (might) get to be an issue if the wires are in separate cables (such as network plus power cable)